# Lucene search using Kibana does return my results

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Using Kibana, I have created the following index:

```
put newsindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards":3,
    "number_of_replicas":2
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "news": {
      "properties": {
        "NewsID": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "NewsType": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "BodyText": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "Caption": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "HeadLine": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "Approved": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "Author": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "Contact": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "DateCreated": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        "DateSubmitted": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have populated the index with Logstash. If I just perform a match_all query, all my records are returned as you'd expect. However, when I try to perform a targeted query such as:

```
get newsindex/_search
{
    "query":{"match": {"headline": "construct abnomolies"}
            }
}
```

I can see headline as a property of _source, but my query is ignored i.e. I still receive everything, regardless of whats in the headline. How do I need to change my index to make headline searchable. I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6.3

Comment: In your mapping, the field is named `HeadLine` not `headline`.

Comment: @Val I've tried both upper and lower. In Kibana whilst creating the query, the predictive text offers both.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that is supposed to match your query?

Comment: They are too long to post on here, but For instance, from the output window in Kibana One of the records I have returned under the _source. I have this, also notice that it's placed the column as lowercase:     `"headline": "Properties’ website is launched",`

Comment: You should make a minimal example -- create a test index with your mapping, index a single document (show the put request you use to index the doc), and show us the mapping (the response from get mapping api), and show the query that fails. Otherwise no one will be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the name property on my index to be lowercase. I noticed in the output windows the the properties under _source where lowercase. In Kibana the predictive text was offering my notation and lowercase. I've dropped my index and re-populated and it now works.